# How to stop Webpack-3's PurifyCSSPlugin from cleaning to much?

Tags: html, css, bulma, webpack-3, purifycss

## Problem

Everything else equal, my final pages differ in their CSS result. The prod version lacks the proper flexbox alignment as seen in the following comparison:

#### Dev

[image: dev page]

#### Prod

[image: prod page]

The problem is caused by the PurifyCSSPlugin. I don't know how to configure it still cleaning up the right parts of the css, keeping the parts I really need?

Any help would be appreciated. The complete code is available [here](https://github.com/lony/js-npm-webpack/tree/4bd3539f32b1915cc60cdb1ad4f2d150bf511205).

## Research so far

#### Update 2017-08-21:

In the production version there is css missing for the following classes

- subtitle

  title:not(.is-spaced) + .subtitle {
      margin-top: -1.5rem;
  }
- columns

  @media screen and (min-width: 769px), print
  .columns:not(.is-desktop) {
      display: flex;
  }

## Setup

I use webpack-3 together with [bulma](http://bulma.io/) to make a [webpage](https://github.com/lony/js-npm-webpack/tree/4bd3539f32b1915cc60cdb1ad4f2d150bf511205). I have two script tasks defined to build my application 1. in development and 2. for production.

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
"prod": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=prod webpack -p",
```

Inside my webpack config I switch between two configurations for the css handling, depending on the NODE_ENV variable. The config looks as follows:

```
const cssConfigEnvironments = {
    'dev': ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader'],
    'prod': ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    })
}
```

In addition I disable the ExtractTextPlugin for development.

```
    new ExtractTextPlugin({                                                                 // Builds .css, see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin
        filename: '[name].css',
        allChunks: true,
        disable: !envIsProd
    }),
```

The only noticeable info shown inside the console is the following deprecation warning:

```
(node:2275) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated. Use Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really coming from the PurifyCSSPlugin there is [an issue already open](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss/issues/161) tackling it.

As a quick fix you have to whitelist the `not` tag:

```
    new PurifyCSSPlugin({
        // Give paths to parse for rules. These should be absolute!
        paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'src/*.html')),
        minimize: envIsProd,
        purifyOptions: {
          info: true,
          whitelist: [ '*:not*' ]
        }
    })
```